# Combining two excel columns and erase the rest

Tags: excel

I would illustrate and show you guys what I mean
This is the Current situation

```
Col A      Col B
123        456
789        789
333        331
abc-222    222
def-111    def
```

the result should be like

```
Col A   Col B
789        789
abc-222    222
def-111    def
```

As I'm new in excel, I do not know how to proceed and execute any scripts.

Thank you guys so much!

EDIT:
The Conditions are as follow, A must contain whatever it is in B for example if A = abcdefg and then B = abc, it will then print out both, but it must be exactly of B. Meaning if B has abc, it must match A or within A and the rest that doesn't fit will be deleted.
NOTE:
By the way, an added notice, because my Col A and Col B have all jumbled values and their everywhere in the column, plus both of the columns have different number of rows..

Comment: Could you try to explain this with words? because your illustration might suggest a "condition" (find B in A), but is not really clear

Comment: What do you mean by "erase"? Really erase, make invisible or do you simply want to apply a filter (and in that case, is it OK to add an extra column on which you will filter?)?

Comment: Erase meaning wipe off and delete, leaving those matched results in the excel

Answer (score 0):

1. In Cell C1, input the following form
   =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B1,A1)), "Yes", "No")
2. Select C1 to C5, then press Ctrl + D
3. Then you will find the rows which applied the rule as "Yes"

Comment: Hi do you know how does vlookup work? I think it should be better.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest a formula like this one (adjusted to include maximum numbers of rows that you will be using):-

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(TRUE,IF(B$2:B$10<>"",ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B$2:B$10,A2))),0)),"Not Found","Found")
```

This has to be entered starting in C2 as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Or here is a non-array-formula version:-

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(1,INDEX((B$2:B$10<>"")*ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B$2:B$10,A2)),,),0)),"Not Found","Found")
```

Then filter on column C.